# What exactly is buffer (last parameter) in io.Copybuffer(...)?

Tags: go, io

I understand it's handy in reusing a buffer rather than allocating every time hen using io.Copy. However, having printed its value several times, I get all zeros and the size of my buffer never changes. I tried to set the size to 8 and 1.

On a related note, to what value should I set my buffer size?

Answer (score 3):

[`io.CopyBuffer()`](https://pkg.go.dev/io#CopyBuffer) documents that:

> ```
> func CopyBuffer(dst Writer, src Reader, buf []byte) (written int64, err error)
> ```
>
> CopyBuffer is identical to Copy except that it stages through the provided buffer (if one is required) rather than allocating a temporary one. If buf is nil, one is allocated; otherwise if it has zero length, CopyBuffer panics.
>
> If either src implements WriterTo or dst implements ReaderFrom, buf will not be used to perform the copy.

So `io.CopyBuffer()` copies data (bytes) from `src` to `dst`. The source is an [`io.Reader`](https://pkg.go.dev/io#Reader) and the destination is an [`io.Writer`](https://pkg.go.dev/io#Writer). These interfaces allow you to read and write slices of bytes (`[]byte`).

In the general case to do the copying, we need a slice to read into from the source, which we can write into the destination. So `io.CopyBuffer()` needs a buffer. The `buf` param allows you to pass a byte slice if you already have one, and if you do so, that buffer will be used to do the job, so no new slice have to be allocated (which would be thrown away at the end of the operation).

What size should it be? The bigger the better, but no bigger is needed than the data you want to copy. Obviously bigger requires more memory, so there's a trade-off. Typically a few KB is a good compromise.

Note that as documented, if the source implements [`io.WriterTo`](https://pkg.go.dev/io#WriterTo) or the destination implements [`io.ReaderFrom`](https://pkg.go.dev/io#ReaderFrom), those interfaces allow to read /
write without having to pass a slice, so in that case the buffer you pass will not be used. Like in this example:

```
srcData := []byte{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}
src := bytes.NewBuffer(srcData)
dst := &bytes.Buffer{}
buf := make([]byte, 10)

io.CopyBuffer(dst, src, buf)

fmt.Println(srcData)
fmt.Println(dst.Bytes())
fmt.Println(buf)
```

Which outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/igh4JfZJklo)):

```
[1 2 3 4 5 6 7]
[1 2 3 4 5 6 7]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
```

Since we used [`bytes.Buffer`](https://pkg.go.dev/bytes#Buffer) as the source and destination (and since it implements both `io.ReaderFrom` and `io.WriterTo`), the buffer is not used.

Let's construct a source and destination that does not implement these interfaces, so we can test if / how our passed buffer is used.

For this, I will embed `*bytes.Buffer` in a struct, but specify a `WriteTo` and `ReadFrom` fields, so those methods will not get promoted from the embedded `bytes.Buffer`:

```
srcData := []byte{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}
src := struct {
    WriteTo int // "disable" WriteTo method
    *bytes.Buffer
}{0, bytes.NewBuffer(srcData)}

dst := struct {
    ReadFrom int // "disable" ReadFrom method
    *bytes.Buffer
}{0, &bytes.Buffer{}}

buf := make([]byte, 10)

io.CopyBuffer(dst, src, buf)

fmt.Println(srcData)
fmt.Println(dst.Bytes())
fmt.Println(buf)
```

This will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/LTU9qmXSsnW)):

```
[1 2 3 4 5 6 7]
[1 2 3 4 5 6 7]
[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 0 0 0]
```

As you can see, the data from the source was read into the buffer, which then was written to the destination.

Note that you may pass a buffer smaller than the data to be copied, in which case reading / writing will be done in several iterations. In such cases, the data in the buffer may hold only the last iteration, and may only hold partial data (if the copied size is not an integer multiplication of the buffer size). It also depends on how the `Read()` method is implemented on the source, as `Read()` is not required to read the full slice passed to it.

Also note that `io.CopyBuffer()` does not document that the data written to the passed buffer is retained, it may get cleared / zeroed. Although this clearing is not implemented for performance reasons, but you should not count on it holding valid data after `io.CopyBuffer()` returns.

Answer (score -1):

When using io.Copy in Go, providing a buffer can improve performance by reducing the number of system calls needed for each read and write operation. However, the buffer size does not determine the size of the data that will be copied. Instead, the buffer size affects the efficiency of the copying process.

The buffer size is typically chosen based on the expected input/output size and the characteristics of the underlying system. There is no fixed rule for selecting the buffer size, as it depends on various factors such as the nature of the data being processed, the available memory, and the performance requirements of your specific use case.

If the buffer size is too small, it may result in frequent buffer flushes and reduce the potential performance gains. On the other hand, if the buffer size is too large, it may lead to unnecessary memory consumption.

To determine an appropriate buffer size, you can consider the following guidelines:

1. Start with a reasonable default size, such as 4096 (4 KB), which is a common choice.
2. Measure the performance of your code with different buffer sizes. You can use tools like Go's testing package or benchmarking utilities to compare the execution time and resource utilization.
3. Adjust the buffer size based on the results. If increasing the buffer size improves performance, you can try larger values. If decreasing it has no significant impact, you can try smaller values.

Remember that the buffer size is not directly related to the size of the data being copied, but rather affects the efficiency of the copying process. Experimentation and performance profiling can help you determine the optimal buffer size for your specific use case.

Comment: This answer looks like ChatGPT

Comment: @DavidW Are you sure?!! If the response is invalid, please let me know which part of the answer is incorrect.

Comment: @DavidW, which part of his answer is wrong?

Comment: I didn't say any part of it was wrong. I said that it looks like ChatGPT. It may possibly be right, but a lot of people have been posting ChatGPT without validating it.